# Send Redirect to current page inside a servlet

Tags: java

I have a URL of a base app like this: http://localhost:8080/abc/
I use request.getRequestURI() inside a servlet named "Login", it return /abc/Login. Now I just want to keep "/abc/" without "Login". So please show how can I do that?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try just:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
```

Comment: Fixed. Would you please try it now? It's been I while I don't work directly with servlets. :-)

Comment: Don't forget to flag the answer as correct so that it can be useful to someone else ;-)